# Does installer for .NET desktop app which can load updates for a website exists?

Tags: .net, windows, com, installation, windows-installer

I need an installer which is capable of

1. mostly silent install of a .NET 3.5 desktop app (Just show one question to user - install or not since app is very simple);
2. can download (part of?) application for the right OS version from right URL;
3. can update registry;
4. can register COM dlls (very important);
5. optionally have an updator which would could download updates from same or another location for the app.

There is no requirement for it to be free but it could be a nice +

Comment: Please see the list of related links to the right of your question. There are probably a hundred questions asking for installer recommendations; you should be able to narrow them by tag and review them to find a solution.